# Find the best linear unbiased estimate

Tags: regression, self-study

[image]

I don't even know how to approach this problem ?
Why are two different models given and how do I interpret the covariance matrix?

Comment: There are not "two different models" here: only one model is exhibited.  The notation is vague, but the frequent appearance of transpose operations suggests the $y_i$ and $x_i$ are intended to be column vectors and the $\beta_{ij}$ are numbers.  Have you been studying multivariate least squares regression?

Comment: no i have been studying multiple linear regression , and thought that it is the case when covariance terms are not zero and variance not equal , please tell me how to interpret the covariance matrix here?

Comment: Let $z=y_2-y_1$, then use $(y_1,z)'$ as response variable to do regression. From given sum of square and sum of cross product, you can get the unbiased estimate fo $\beta$s.

Comment: This covariance matrix assumes the errors in $(y_1,y_2)$ are correlated with correlation coefficient $1/2.$  This problem is a nice introduction to multivariate OLS for those who are familiar with generalized (univariate) OLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\beta = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \beta_{11} & \beta_{12} & \beta_{21} & \beta_{22} \end{array} } \right]'$

Re-write the model as 
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   y_1\\y_2 \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x_1 & x_2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x_3 &x_4\end{array} } \right] \beta + \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \epsilon_1\\ \epsilon_2 \end{array} } \right]$$

Let $z=y_2-y_1$ we have

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   y_1\\z \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   y_1\\y_2-y_1 \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x_1 & x_2 & 0 & 0 \\ -x_1 & -x_2 & x_3 &x_4\end{array} } \right] \beta + \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \epsilon_1\\ \epsilon_2 \end{array} } \right]$$ 
Then $$Cov(y_1,z) = \sigma^2I_2$$

The question becomes (common) linear model
$$Y=X\beta+\epsilon$$
The BLUE (best linear unbiased estimate) of $\beta$ is $\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$.

Need to construct $X'X$ and $X'Y$ from given sum of square and sum of the cross product.

Generally, for a multivariate linear model, if you can find $A$ such that $Var(AY) = I\sigma^2$, then the multivariate linear can be convert into univariate linear model.